# jQuery Connected Sortable Lists, Save Order to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

Hoping that using something like this demo it is possible to drag items within and between two columns, and update their order either live or with a "save" button to MySQL. Point being that you can make changes and return to the page later to view or update your ordering.

http://pilotmade.com/examples/draggable/

Doing it for just one column is fine, but when I try to pass the order of both columns, the issue seems to be passing multiple serialized arrays with jQuery to a PHP/MySQL update script.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

If you look below, I want to pass say...

sortable1
entry_1 => 0
entry_5 => 1

sortable2
entry_3 => 0
entry_2 => 1
entry_4 => 2

EDIT: This ended up doing the trick

HTML

```
<ol id="sortable1"><li id="entry_####">blah</li></ol>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable(
    {
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        update : function () 
        { 
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "phpscript",
                data: 
                {
                    sort1:$("#sortable1").sortable('serialize'),
                    sort2:$("#sortable2").sortable('serialize')
                },
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $('.success').fadeIn(500);
                    $('.success').fadeOut(500);
                }
            });
        } 
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

This is the PHP query

```
parse_str($_REQUEST['sort1'], $sort1);
foreach($sort1['entry'] as $key=>$value)
{
do stuff
}
```

Comment: can we see your code so we can see where you went wrong ?

Comment: I edited to show the jQuery & html code. I guess my question is really about how to pass the serialized data from this to the php insert/update script.

Comment: where exactly are you having a problem is serialized data not formatted right or are you just not sure how to get the posted data into your database ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what I would do is split them up

```
   data    :
    {
      sort1:$('#sortable1').sortable('serialize'),
      sort2:$('#sortable2').sortable('serialize')
    }
```

then when you post you can get the request and set them as needed, I hope that makes sense

so what I do is this

```
parse_str($_REQUEST['sort1'],$sort1); 

foreach($sort1 as $key=>$value){
    //do sutff;
}
```

Comment: this makes sense, re: your question above about my problem, I guess now that I know I can split the serialized data into two segments, do they now get passed as $_POST['sort1'] and $_POST['sort2'] ? I "think" if that works I should be all set. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: One final question... is the correct loop to get the arrays values for inserting into the db: foreach($_POST['sort1'] as $key=>$value) { do this } Thought I understood how this should work...

Comment: That did the trick, everything is working, thanks for making my day mmcgrail!